# Is it possible to disable osgi in Jboss 7.1.1 (with liferay)?

Tags: jboss, osgi, liferay, jboss7.x, liferay-6

[I tried going into the standalone.xml file and removed all references to anything related to osgi.  However, the issue still exists.  Is there something else I need to do for AS7.1.1.Final to actually disable osgi?](https://community.jboss.org/thread/224319)
Or is there some way I can force it to load missing modules?

Needed because I have a test @Singleton @LocalBean deployed as part of my war file, but as soon as I implement [javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization.html), I get the following useless exception which doesn't give me any clue as to how to fix it. Note that the ejb get's loaded fine when just dumping in jboss, but then liferay doesn't know about the portlets..
Since osgi is going to be removed in future wildfly releases, I thought it will be simplest to just get rid of it now..

```
00:34:30,237 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class com.example.ebr.db.TestSingleton1 in Module "deployment.ebr-eds-mdr-plugin.war:main" from Service Module Loader
: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/example/ebr/db/TestSingleton1 (Module "deployment.ebr-eds-mdr-plugin.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/SessionSynchronization
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization from [Module "deployment.ebr-eds-mdr-plugin.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 24 more
```

My META-INF/MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1384910505626
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Built-By: amanica
Bundle-Description: 
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.example.com/
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ebr-eds-mdr-plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.ebr-eds-mdr-plugin
Bundle-Vendor: Example
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.example.testvaadinportlet;uses:="com.vaadin.ui,javax
 .naming,org.apache.log4j,com.example.ebr.db,javax.portlet,com.example
 .ebr.report.db,com.vaadin.data,javax.sql,com.vaadin.server";version="
 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT",com.example.ebr.db;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.ejb,
 org.apache.log4j";version="0.0.1.SNAPSHOT",com.example.ebr.report;use
 s:="com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations,javax.xml.bind.annotation,org.
 slf4j,com.example.ebr.report.config,com.vaadin.data,com.vaadin.ui,com
 .vaadin.data.util,com.example.ebr.report.db,com.vaadin.server,org.apa
 che.log4j,javax.portlet";version="0.0.1.SNAPSHOT",com.example.ebr.rep
 ort.birt;uses:="com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec,org.eclipse.birt.report.engi
 ne.api,com.example.ebr.report,org.apache.commons.io,org.eclipse.birt.
 core.exception,org.eclipse.birt.core.framework,org.slf4j";version="0.0.
 1.SNAPSHOT",com.example.ebr.report.config;uses:="com.vaadin.data,org.
 slf4j,com.vaadin.ui,com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations,com.example.
 ebr.report.birt,com.example.ebr.report,com.vaadin.server,com.vaadin.s
 hared.ui.label,org.eclipse.birt.core.exception,com.example.ebr.report
 .db,org.apache.log4j,com.vaadin.addon.ipcforliferay.event,javax.portlet
 ,com.vaadin.addon.ipcforliferay,javax.xml.bind.annotation,org.apache.co
 mmons.lang3";version="0.0.1.SNAPSHOT",com.example.ebr.report.db;uses:
 ="javax.naming,org.apache.log4j,javax.sql,com.thoughtworks.xstream,com.
 example.ebr.report,com.example.ebr.report.config";version="0.0.1.SN
 APSHOT"
Import-Package: com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec;version="[2.1,3)",com.thought
 works.xstream,com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations,com.vaadin.addon.ipc
 forliferay,com.vaadin.addon.ipcforliferay.event,com.vaadin.data;version
 ="[7.1,8)",com.vaadin.data.util;version="[7.1,8)",com.vaadin.server;ver
 sion="[7.1,8)",com.vaadin.shared.ui.label;version="[7.1,8)",com.vaadin.
 ui;version="[7.1,8)",javax.annotation;version="[1.1,2)",javax.ejb;versi
 on="[3.1,4)",javax.ejb.api,javax.naming,javax.portlet;version="[2.0,3)"
 ,javax.sql,javax.xml.bind.annotation;version="[2.2,3)",org.apache.commo
 ns.io;version="[2.2,3)",org.apache.commons.lang3;version="[3.1,4)",org.
 apache.log4j;version="[1.2,2)",org.eclipse.birt.core.exception,org.ecli
 pse.birt.core.framework,org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api,org.slf4j;ve
 rsion="[1.7,2)"
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open standalone.xml (or whatever configuration are you using)

and remove whole element `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.x">`

or you can connect via jboss-cli / jboss-admin to server and run

```
/subsystem=osgi:remove
```

and restart server afterwards.